# Symfony Form: how to set the entity being created as target for new unidirectional relation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have a form for an entity that is by design potentially the target of many different types of relations; let's name it *ManyTargetClass*. Currently this *ManyTargetClass* is the inverse side of those relations using bidirectional relations. I can't change the fact that this class is the target of many relations. But I thought it doesn't look very good to have a bidirectional relationship for all the possible types of relations as it pollutes my *ManyTargetClass* with lots of inverse-side fields as well as their getters and setters and all this.

(Or is it normal?)

I am currently mitigating this with traits to reduce the visual clutter but I am not entirely happy with it, even though there are actual use-cases for reuse of those traits.

So I thought it would be better to have my *RelatingClass1, RelatingClass2,...* declare a unidirectional ManyToOne-relation to *ManyTargetClass* to get rid of the complexity on the inverse side.

But I failed to find a way to incorporate that into my form workflow when I want to go the unidirectional route. Remark that the *RelatingClassX*-classes are never created on their own.
They are always created via embedded forms in forms for other classes. This finally leads to my actual problem.

I want to create a *ManyTargetClass*-instance with embedded Forms that let me create *RelationClassX*-instances, automatically setting the *ManyTargetClass*-entity currently being created as target for the unidirectional relation established by the *RelatinClassX*-entity being created (preferable not having to lift potentially existing non-nullable-constraints on the join-column-definition of the *RelationgClassX*-side, if that is not possible I can lift this constraint though).

Is that possible? If yes: is it advisable and how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Too much code in entity

Creating many getters and setters in *ManyTargetClass* is nothing wrong. I have same thoughts when I started with Doctrine. You can think about entities as documentation to what is in database and what relations are there. You want to check your entity in the future and want to read what exactly it does.

#### Traits

That's same for traits. Don't overdo your code with traits and keep entities as simple as you can. Even the entities are huge.

#### Consider performance

Yours only concern should be about performance. Solution for that is unidirectional relations or  **fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"**.

More info: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

#### How to create form while using unidirectional relation

Create form with **mapped=false**. You can attach those entities to parent yourselves in Controller.

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped

I'm not sure if I get your point. Provide some code examples of form and entities if my answer doesn't fit.

Comment: This already helped, so thanks for that! Do I understand correctly: I would set the property for *RelatingClassXY* to mapped=false and read the form information inside the controller. Then I would create the instance(s) of *RelatingClassXY" inside the controller? And how I read the doc you linked, performance has to be considered when I have many associated objects for a relation but that's pretty much never the case for me. It is just that I have many relations (like 50) with a very small amount of related objects each. Would that speak for bidirectional relations to keep controllers simple?

Comment: I would choose bidirectional relation here only if you often access child classes from parent. Use it only if it’s beneficial for you and doesn’t have visible impact on performance. You don’t need to create child classes yourselves. Embeded form can be mapped=false with **data_class** option set to your child object class.

Comment: Yeah...the data is pretty much interwoven and many things have relations to other things and I need lots of separate entities to describe the relations as there will be additional information on the relation itself. It is kinda like a very common pattern that derives itself from the context. So I think I will go the bidirectional route as my hope is that readability will improve in the end. If I run into performance problems I will have to see how to tackle them the best way. Thanks for your input!